# Get deive token by using cordova

Tags: cordova

Hi is thire any way to get device token only

since cordova-plugin-fcm can do this job, but i dont want to include in my ios project their is some conflicts between manually added Firebase and cordova-plugin-fcm

then how will i simply get  device token ?is thire any limited cordova plugin?

Comment: you can use onesignal Push notification for Android, IOS, Windows. here is doc https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/ionic-sdk-setup

Comment: ok now their is no conflicts but i cant get device token using window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
  console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
  alert("userId = " + ids.userId + ", pushToken = " + ids.pushToken);
});

Comment: you can follow integration guide, you need userId to send push notification on device, login with onsignal account to send push notification or use REST API for same.

Comment: ok it means i only get the token after  onesignal registerd account